# Creating a custom carouse plugin in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

[image]

Trying to recreate this, Does anyone know how?

Basically, it's a list of devs in that project and I want to make it carousel-like. where-by the item in the middle is always larger than the rest.

Comment: Actually, you need to show what you already have tried because Stack Overflow doesn't support just showing some design and asking for the codes.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  There are lots of Angular carousel libraries you could use, or do none of those do what you want?

Comment: [Demo](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/basic/carousel) - [code](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/carousel/src) - [usage](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/app/pages/basic/carousel)

Comment: @Md.RakibulIslam, sorry with the way i put my question, what i wanted to ask was if there were any libraries that could recreate this exact image, i have used bootstrap carousel, its not even close to what i want to achieve. if there is any other carousel libraries you known I'd appreciate. if not, ill try recreating it from scratch.

Comment: @ChrisBarr i only know of Ngx-bootstrap, Bootstrap, and angular materials. and they done give me this exact code. i'll just try recreating it from scratch, wanted to be sure there wasnt any library that could do this. Thank you!

Comment: Well it's really hard to tell what you want here.  How are all the carousel libraries people have linked to not what you want? All we have to go off of is a screenshot of some website you like. Do you want circles as images? What are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use third party npm pakage then i would suggest https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-slick-carousel .

Here is a tutorial you can follow: https://www.positronx.io/angular-slick-carousel-slider-integration-tutorial/